# How to complile boost Library for iOS 6?

Tags: boost, osx-lion, xcode4.5

I am using Boost Library in my application. i want to compile boost library for iOS6.

i am using Mac OS X 10.6
X code 4.5

any only please let mem know?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ofxiOSBoost static libraries and headers:

(works for iOS 6, iOS 7, iOS 8 + )

Releases for libc++ (c++11), libstdc++, build scripts included as well

https://github.com/danoli3/ofxiOSBoost